# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: films in Autocomplete

Tags: react-native, variables, autocomplete

I need to use an autocomplete in my app,
I'm using this library because it was the only one I found 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-autocomplete-input

and this way it is working.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Autocomplete from 'react-native-autocomplete-input';

export default class Registrar extends Component{
  state = {
    films: [],
    query: '',
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const json = require('../assets/json/titles.json');
    const { results: films } = json;
    this.setState({ films });
  }

  findFilm(query) {
    if (query === '') {
      return [];
    }

    const { films } = this.state;
    const regex = new RegExp(`${query.trim()}`, 'i');
    return films.filter(film => film.title.search(regex) >= 0);
  }

  render() {

    const { query } = this.state;
    const films = this.findFilm(query);
    const comp = (a, b) => a.toLowerCase().trim() === b.toLowerCase().trim();

    return(
         <Autocomplete
          autoCapitalize="none"
          style={styles.input}
          autoCorrect={false}
          data={films.length === 1 && comp(query, films[0].title) ? [] : films}
          defaultValue={query}
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text })}
          placeholder="Enter the film title"
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ query: item.title })}>
              <Text style={styles.itemText}>
                {item.title} ({item.release_date})
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        />
   }
}
```

However, my code requires  to be inside a function, as in the example below, but it generates the following error **ReferenceError: Can't find variable: films**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Autocomplete from 'react-native-autocomplete-input';

export default class Registrar extends Component{
  state = {
    films: [],
    query: '',
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const json = require('../assets/json/titles.json');
    const { results: films } = json;
    this.setState({ films });
  }

  findFilm(query) {
    if (query === '') {
      return [];
    }

    const { films } = this.state;
    const regex = new RegExp(`${query.trim()}`, 'i');
    return films.filter(film => film.title.search(regex) >= 0);
  }

  renderInputField() {
      return (
          <Autocomplete
          autoCapitalize="none"
          style={styles.input}
          autoCorrect={false}
          data={films.length === 1 && comp(query, films[0].title) ? [] : films}
          defaultValue={query}
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text })}
          placeholder="Enter the film title"
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ query: item.title })}>
              <Text style={styles.itemText}>
                {item.title} ({item.release_date})
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        />
      )
  }

  render() {

    const { query } = this.state;
    const films = this.findFilm(query);
    const comp = (a, b) => a.toLowerCase().trim() === b.toLowerCase().trim();

    return(
         {this.renderInputField()}
   }
}
```

I need it to be within a function because this field must appear when answering yes in the previous question

Please, Help me!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like following. Just add `construtor` to your `class`

```
export default class Registrar extends Component{
  construtor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      films: [],
      query: '',
    }
  }
}
```

Otherwise check the error line number(it will display with the error), then you can easily find out where its occurred.